# Doctrine in laravel, getting all user's roles

Tags: laravel, doctrine-orm

I have a simple project in laravel 5.4 with Doctrine 2.0. I have three tables: **users**, **roles**, **user_roles**. Screenshot from tables schemas from HEIDISQL I show below:

**users**:
[image: adas]

**roles**:
[image]

**user_roles**:
[image]

I have three Entities classes for each table of course:

```php
<?php
namespace TodoList\Http\Entities;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;



/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")

 */

class User 
{


    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * 
     */
    private $name;
     /**
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * 
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Task", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
     * @var ArrayCollection|Task[]
     */
     private $tasks;
     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserRole", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $user_roles;


     /**
      * User constructor
      * @param @name
      * @param @email
      * @param $password
      */
     public function __construct($name, $email) {


         $this->name = $name;
         $this->email = $email;
         $this->tasks = new ArrayCollection();
         $this->user_roles = new ArrayCollection();
     }

     /**
      * 
      * @return mixed
      * 
      * 
      */

     public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTasks()
    {
        return $this->tasks;
    }
    public function addTask(Task $task)
    {
        if(!$this->tasks->contains($task)) {

            $task->setUser($this);
            $this->tasks->add($task);
        }
    }
    public function getId(){

        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getUserRoles(){

        return $this->user_roles;
    }


}


<?php
namespace TodoList\Http\Entities;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="roles")
 * 
 */
class Role{

     /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
     */
    private $description;

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserRole", mappedBy="role",cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $user_roles;

    public function getId(){

        return $this->id;

    }
    public function getName(){

        return $this->name;
    }
    public function getDescription(){

        return $this->description;

    }

 }


<?php
namespace TodoList\Http\Entities;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_roles")
 */
class UserRole
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="user_roles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="user_roles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $role;

    public function setUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \NVC\UserBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Set recipe
     *
     * @param \NVC\RecipeBundle\Entity\Recipe $recipe
     * @return UserRecipeAssociation
     */
    public function setRole(Role $role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get recipe
     *
     * @return \NVC\RecipeBundle\Entity\Recipe
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }
}
```

I have a problem when I'm trying retrieve roles of particular user by doctrine Entity Managar. I'm trying to do that in that way:

```
public function showUserRoles(EntityManagerInterface $em){

        $userRoles = $em->getRepository('\TodoList\Http\Entities\UserRole');
        $userRoles->findBy(['user' => 2]);
        //count($userRole);


    }
```

There is an error from method **findBy** 
Error message is:

> (1/1) FatalErrorException
>   Doctrine\Common\Proxy\AbstractProxyFactory::getProxyDefinition():
>   Failed opening required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\storage\proxies__CG__TodoListHttpEntitiesRole.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Is anything wrong with my Entities? I don't know how could I solve that problem. Could someone help me with that?
I would be very greateful
Best regards ;)

Comment: Doctrine not configured properly.

Comment: How could I configure doctrine propery?

Comment: The official Doctrine's documentation is enough. Especially the proxy directory must be set and must be writable by the web server process

Answer (score 0):

You need to set folder `C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\storage\proxies\` as writable and then you need to generate proxies by console command:

```
doctrine:generate:proxies
```